# How to remove event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
event.preventDefault();
var $data = $("#form");
    $.post($("#form").attr("action"), $data.serializeArray(), function(data) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(response.error == 'yes') // my code is ok here
                $("#error").stop().empty().show().html('<div id="resp_message">'+response.message+'</div>').fadeOut(5000);
        else // but here wont work
                $("#form").submit();
    });
});
```

All I want to do is to display message or submit if the query is ok.
Please help me.

Comment: im a newbie pls help.. thanks in advance

Comment: oh theres no error in my code here but the location to where my form is submit at first it submit through ajax and get the output in json_encode but if the query is correct i wrote a header location so the json_encode no longer to see but the another page again so in "if(response.error == 'yes') and else"  no longer json encode to test if no error in my query

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery.off to remove your .on binding which will then allow you to bind another on click handler that does not have the preventDefault in there

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: my code only need one click then go either display error message or go to the next page

Comment: oh theres no error in my code here but the location to where my form is submit at first it submit through ajax and get the output in json_encode but if the query is correct i wrote a header location so the json_encode no longer to see but the another page again so in "if(response.error == 'yes') and else"  no longer json encode to test if no error in my query

Comment: OK sorry but I don't really understand what you are asking for